# Can't withdraw from blockchain.info: "Private key does not match bitcoin address [my address] = [probablyprivkey1] | [probablyprivkey2]"

Tags: blockchain.info, private-key, withdrawal

I have some BTC (and I really need money now) on my Blockchain.info account, I can't withdraw them (just send them to another BTC address) as it tells me "Private key does not match bitcoin address [my address] = [probablyprivkey1] | [probablyprivkey2]"

The address was created on blockchain.info, not imported.

The incomes are from Apr 03, 2013, and although I was trying to withdraw them for some time, now I've realized that is the last time those bitcoins will be a really large amount of money for me — 0.3651BTC (I'm living in Poland, so it is ~360.59PLN).

I haven't found an answer on forums, so I decided to ask about it myself.

Comment: Did you try contacting their [customer service](https://blockchain.zendesk.com/home)?

Comment: I don't understand. Why is it that you can send your Bitcoins to a different address, but you can't withdraw? Aren't the two the same?

Comment: Their support team is good - open a ticket if you haven't already. Perhaps it relates to something they've changed in the back-end. I've used BCi a lot and never seen that error.

Comment: Or.. go to the BCi address book and find the address with the funds in it, then go to settings/advanced and export the private key for that address. Then import the key into a light desktop client such as MultiBit and send using that.

Comment: @NickODell I meant that by withdrawal I meant sending.

Comment: @GeorgeKimionis Tried. No response yet. I know I should wait, but I'm in quite a hurry and I wanted to know whether sombody already got the money back maybe. Thanks for a suggestion.

Comment: @George well, the problem appeared back in 2013 or the beginning of 2014, and there are some forum threads on the Internet from this time, among others one was from December 2013. It was probably a rather larger problem. Thanks for a hope.

Comment: @George You seem to talk about some old Blockchain UI... there's no 'Advanced'; I have MultiBit, and tried importing wallet.aes.json but it requires .key

Comment: I'm not familiar with MultiBit but if you open that .json file in a text editor you'll see the private keys (it needs to be an unencrypted export). Then follow this guide https://multibit.org/v0.5/help_importASingleKey.html to import the relevant key(s).

Comment: @George Hmmm... So I have to just modify .key... I was just thinking it's binary without actually checking. Thanks, I'll try it!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ArchieT/51f8d2541d58da7479c8f778160925fc Here I tried https://github.com/prof7bit/wallet-key-tool, same error. First with a wrong password, and then with a correct one.

Comment: welp. now it's worth 11kPLN, about my yearly expenses on everything except room rental.

Comment: new UI of blockchain info wallet allowed me to generate a signature, but an online checker just said "Invalid data" to it. And trying to send money results in error. Trying to export results in "Unsupported Key Format".

Comment: my username on GitHub changed from ArchieT to mkf, so adjust the above gist links